# How to support multiple file formats and field delimiters?

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii

A file with contents in table form can be exported in at least 3 formats (UTF-8, UTF-16LE, Ascii), have columns that are tab-separated, pilcrow separated, or other, and have quotes/thorns/etc. around each item. The following function reads in a table that is UTF-8, separated by pilcrows, and each item is surrounded by thorns.

```
def read_app_dat(app_export):
    """ Reads and parses DAT exported from App

    Assumes that delimiters are concordance.

    Args:
        app_export: str, file path to DAT exported by App
    Returns:
        Dictionary where ID is mapped to a list where the first
        tuple is URI ID
    """
    app_dict = {}
    f = codecs.open(app_export, encoding='utf-8')
    for line in f:
        each_row = re.sub(r'\xfe', "", line).split("\x14")
        if "ID" in each_row[0] or "URI" in each_row[1]:
            pass
        else:
            app_dict[each_row[0]] = each_row[1]
    return app_dict
```

As it's currently written, I would need to define each row differently for each scenario.

```
each_row = re.sub(r'\xfe', "", line).split("\x14")
```

That's not a very pythonic thing to do. How could I better deal with separators, in this case Pilcrows and thorns, so that I could call them as a parameter? The [codecs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) module has been the most helpful so far.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you think about using `csv` module from stdlib (https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html)?

Comment: It looks like a better way to do it. My assumption was that I wasn't dealing with comma-separated-values so not to look at the module more closely. I think my assumption is probably wrong, thank you.

Comment: A remaining question is how to deal with the different types of separators like Pilcrows. They can appear differently within the file depending on the formatting used.

Comment: Just read the docs about the module better. There are several types of  separators that you should specify.

Comment: You're right, csv module is definitely the way to go.